# JUnit classloader issues when moving to Maven with System properties and static fields

Tags: java, maven, junit, classloader

I'm working on converting our legacy build from using Ant to Maven (3.3.3, if that matters), and ran into a snag. Our codebase has a class that initializes a private static field from system properties, which typically are populated by a launch script on application invocation. The unit test which exercises this code is setting the system properties before executing the test. When running the unit test in either Ant or through the Eclipse JUnit runner, everything works fine. When running through maven, it seems that the static field is initialized before the unit test executes, causing the properties to not be present, and the test to fail.

I've put together a sample class and unit test to demonstrate, as I'm not allowed to post the actual code here.

```
package foo.bar;

public class ValueClass { 
    private static final String SAMPLE_FIELD = "Foo " + System.getProperty("target.value");

    private final myValueField;

    public ValueClass() {
        myValueField = "random text " + SAMPLE_FIELD;
    }

    public String getValueField() { 
        return myValueField;
    }
}
```

And the corresponding unit test:

```
package foo.bar;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;

public class ValueClassTest { 

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupBeforeClasses() { 
        System.setProperty("target.value", "value from test");
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetValueField() { 
        String expected = "random text Foo value from test";

        ValuesClass valuesClassInstance = new ValuesClass();

        String actual = valuesClassInstance.getValueField();

        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }  
}
```

As I mentioned, when I execute using Ant or Eclipse, everything works fine. I've played around with some logging (dropping some log messages into a static block in the ValueClass), and determined that when running in Eclipse or Ant, the class is loaded during the testGetValueField method's execution, and in Maven, the class is loaded sometime before the setupBeforeClasses method is executed. This causes the SAMPLE_FIELD to be initialized with null values from the "target.value" system property.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Rob

Comment: Just tried this with Maven... Works just fine.

Comment: Also works from IntelliJ... whatever is causing this issue, it does not seem to be Maven... maybe clean up your pom, some plugin may be instantiating classes before your tests run?

Comment: That's a good thought... I'll search for anything else using ValueClass in other tests. When I was testing it in standalone mode through Eclipse, I was only executing the one class.

Comment: Sure enough, there was another class referencing ValueClass in a test executing earlier in the process.

Comment: Unless you make sure that no reference is made to this ValueClass from any other test or code that gets executed before this test runs, the class will be created by the JVM before your @BeforeClass method runs. This is almost impossible to work reliably. Set the system properties from the pom or something that runs before any tests start, and remember that there should be no ordering between your tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can set the System properties from the `pom.xml`, then stop doing it from the `@BeforeClass` method and [try this](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html):

```
<project>
        [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <propertyName>propertyValue</propertyName>
            <buildDirectory>${project.build.directory}</buildDirectory>
            [...]
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
        [...]
</project>
```

Comment: That worked... To maintain support for executing the test in Eclipse, I need to keep the original setupBeforeClasses method in there, duplicating the initialization for both scenarios.  I'll go forward with that, and just comment the heck out of it. On a related note, do you have any idea why the two classloader types would be behaving differently?

Comment: After a suggestion from a comment on the above, I looked into the execution order of the tests, and there's a different test that references ValueClass. Instead of the classloader being different (which is scary), the Unit tests are just executing in a different order (which is far less scary).

Comment: Worked in Eclipse by accident... it just happened that the tests ran in an order that it made things work... unless you forked every test, which you can do from Maven and Eclipse, but it's expensive to start the JVM for each test, so you should try to avoid that.

Comment: BTW this is not a classloader issue. The JVM classloader is required to instantiate classes at first use, so the behaviour is exactly the same in any JVM as far as I know....